# Создание кроссплатформенного приложения, требуется помощь

Tags: php, java, база-данных, kotlin, кроссплатформенность

**Здравствуйте, сразу извиняюсь за много букв и вопросов.**

Пожалуй начну с предистории. Имеется web приложение, по сути это CRM система для ведения бухгалтерии.

CRM была полностью написана на собственном фреймворке (который в свою очередь написан на PHP), так же используется база данных MySQL.

**Что мне необходимо на данный момент?**

Необходимо создать десктопное приложение и приложение для android (рассматривалось и создание приложения под mac|ios). Приложение должно работать в оффлайн и онлайн режиме, то есть пользователь сможет ввести данные в оффлайн режиме и при подключении к интернету данные синхронизируются с сервером.

**После этого начинаются проблемы, особенно адаптацией приложения под android.**

Какие технологии для этого подходят лучше всего? Смотрел на React Native, но насколько я понимаю - у него существует множество минусов, не лучше ли будет написать desctop приложение на java/kotlin и после адаптировать его под android?

До этого у меня не было опыта в создании приложений под android / ios.

Так же проблемы с базой данных, как её лучше всего хранить в оффлайн режиме?

Смотрел в сторону SQLite, но более привлекают различные ORM. Как лучше организовать хранение / синхронизацию БД с приложением / сервером?

**Заранее спасибо за ответ, надеюсь на помощь.**

Comment: У вас слишком много вопросов :) А так React Native отвечает вашим требованием. Вполне возможно сделать самому. Конечно лучше всего использовать родные для системы языки, но это только в случае наличия большего количества времени и специалистов.

Comment: Как лучше организовать синхронизацию БД -- это второй большой вопрос.
Через логи событий, например. И главное, как ее мержить.

Comment: @Mister_Jesus, спасибо за совет. Времени как раз не так много, всё же и сам смотрю в сторону RN :)

Comment: https://engineering.linkedin.com/distributed-systems/log-what-every-software-engineer-should-know-about-real-time-datas-unifying

Answer (score -1):

Думаю, вам мог бы подойти [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/). Они недавно выпустили новую версию, Web перешел с бета-версии в стабильный релиз. Так что можно написать на дарте веб.приложение, и через Flutter же адаптировать его на андроид, и позже по необходимости на iOS. Это выйдет проще, чем для каждой платформы отдельно пилить
По работе с БД не подскажу